# SOME jQuery click events not working on iPad

Tags: jquery, html, ipad

I'm developing an iPad-specific HTML page (to be packaged in a "reader" app). The problem is, the "click" events on one of the lists (the "Location" list) is absolutely not working. The weirdness is that click events on all other divs work *just fine.*

So I've tried the basic methods of convincing iOS to cooperate (pointer: cursor and the onclick="" method). I've even added "touchstart" bindings to all my click events for these .location_list_item elements. I'm stumped.

The site is prototyped at http://evankerrickford.com/lumenisapp. Works fine on desktop, absolutely broken on iPad just because of these click functions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a missing `]` in one of my innerHTML functions. Worked on desktop, broke mobile. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try with "on" function

```
$('selector').on('click touchstart', function() {

});
```